# play .wav file using c language

Tags: c, playsound

I was asked to play .wav files using C language, the compiler I'm using is Devcpp.
I was trying to use the function `PlaySound()` as below:

```
PlaySound("C:/Users/wavfiles/13.1.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
```

If I directly input the directory to the function like this, it is able to successfully play the sound.

However, I want to set the directory as a variable. I create a text file with a list of directory and extract the one that I want, then put it into `PlaySound()` function. Here is part of my code:

```
FILE *fw;
char addr[1000]
char schapter[50];

while(fgets(addr, 1000, fw) != NULL) {
    if((strstr(addr, schapter)) != NULL) {   
        printf("\n%s", addr);
        PlaySound(addr, NULL, SND_FILENAME); 
    }
}
```

In this case, the directory is assigned to `addr` (`addr = "C:/Users/wavfiles/13.1.wav"`) and then I put `addr` into `PlaySound()`, but it doesn't work.

I have been stuck on this problem for a long time and cannot move on.
I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me suggestions or solutions.
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you need to use double slash instead of single slash in the address. Hint: escape sequences

Comment: A single backslash (when entered on the command line).

Comment: @GargAnkit: That shouldn't be a problem entering things on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string returned by `fgets()` contains the terminal newline. You'll need to remove that to get the filename.

An easy way to do this is to use `strchr()` to locate the newline:

```
while (fgets(addr, 1000, fw) != NULL) {
    char *nl = strchr(addr, '\n');
    if (nl) *nl = 0;
    …
}
```

Comment: I see, it is quite make sense, but I added the code you said:    `while(fgets(addr, 1000, fw) != NULL) {
  char *nl = strchr(addr,'\n');
        if (nl) *nl = 0;  
  
  `if((strstr(addr, schapter)) != NULL) { `
            printf("\n%s",addr);
            PlaySound(addr, NULL, SND_FILENAME); 
        }
 }`   but the sound still cannot play. Is there something wrong with the declaration or the PlaySound() function?